# Python dramatically slowing down after variable hits certain size

Tags: python, performance, variables, size

I am developing a robot simulation in MuJoCo using Python.

I am logging Position, setpoints and forces at each iteration of a rate at 30 times per second.

I used to do this to a log file, but noticed it is much faster to do so to a variable.
So I add every entry as string to a variable and write this one after Simulation ended.
Normally logging to the variable takes under 0.1ms

After a long time, suddenly the longtime is MUCH longer. Like 16ms for one log which alows everything down to sub real time.

I suspect this is due to the variable becoming to large and some things happening. If I reduce the logging rate to like 10, logging stays at 0.1ms.

This happens at around 300ish s, or at iteration step 12000. Every step i log something like this:

```
1647378205250937938
0.43045029044151306 0.41614729166030884 0.4489428400993347 0.47255557775497437 0.42031413316726685 0.4088066518306732 0.41645869612693787 0.3970390856266022 0.5040341019630432 0.3946106433868408 0.4364241659641266 0.456932932138443 0.4085571765899658 0.40109333395957947 0.409419983625412 0.389591246843338 0.08292744308710098 0.14190182089805603 0.11143133044242859 0.15836814045906067 0.17158323526382446 0.21875925362110138 0.1706666350364685 0.16594353318214417 0.20744433999061584 0.15767113864421844 0.046615272760391235 0.04684748873114586 0.04596294090151787 0.0 0.05029720067977905 0.0 0.04672761633992195 0.04756950959563255 0.0 0.0475701168179512 0.0 0.04596245661377907
0.4455847369001088 0.41615852894453065 0.44892597074751384 0.4725248055169209 0.4202857129317141 0.4087280349075159 0.42755667112426493 0.39705052703503135 0.5200858367265269 0.39463004705855786 0.43641740149804753 0.4569155145677277 0.40851694777886105 0.4010295166248054 0.4205297687428346 0.38958620801574995 0.08295025561421883 0.14187967123574474 0.11128058163615122 0.15858062613853713 0.17166556519308876 0.2187238086861399 0.17067735850672347 0.1658828314725 0.2074619539922316 0.15763205790213541 0.04661500341387697 0.04684767745742507 0.045963186684294936 0.07032186421375966 0.05029701391508684 0.07032717042877357 0.046727249159162175 0.047569159491532696 0.06830912325185874 0.04757051197783842 0.06859462107875174 0.04596273862032113
-152.0 -54.64886139280563 -54.31433397029253 -55.08738846537631 -48.83185000952511 -39.331178253691355 -152.0 -52.2570146697172 -152.0 -53.2218603617448 -54.34320396795293 -55.242635968871234 -45.44705813076688 -40.7226589398898 -152.0 -48.671147762476 -14.15811340383344 -14.500547922824008 0.0 -54.16315494993855 -21.83494003230314 -27.76439436068745 -21.683905703218088 -21.036989920605468 -26.357840612265683 -13.772156222608821 -5.876765096320226 -5.98009974286319 -5.876879214924671 0.0 -6.357606542838144 0.0 -5.8752227485834 -5.98484806815704 0.0 -6.105103164960943 0.0 -5.882726917822228
```

The full code can be seen here:
https://github.com/Roboy/mujoco_roboy/blob/PID_flo/src/simulation.py

Comment: Can you include some code? Like a small example

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running out of RAM and that the OS isn't resorting to [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging)?

Comment: Have you checked out buffering log writes via a memory handler? https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler

Comment: @JonSG Python 2 is end-of-life; please provide docs for Python 3

Comment: "After a long time" How much? few minutes? hours? days? month? How much memory do you have? Please provide more information about the context (like the hardware and a piece of code). By the way, do you need all the logs? Do you need them to be so precise? (seriously 15 digits...)

Comment: The whole code is really large but can be seen here:

This should not be a RAM issue as the logfile is in the region of 10MB after writing to the disk in the end. 

I will check out the memory handler. Looks exactly as what i need! Thanks a lot.

Comment: "After a long time" Is specified later in my post. The actual time does not matter at all, rather the simulation step at which it occurs. 
Sadly i indeed need that kind of precision

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler for the latest

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing each entry as you process it or waiting until processing all entries to write them all at once, you could collect entries until reaching some threshold and then write those ones, then empty the collection and continue. This saves time switching between processing and writing to disk because you're only doing it every *n* times instead of every single time, and if you set the threshold right, you won't get a slowdown due to running out of memory.

Comment: This is also my workaround for now. The only problem with this is that the loop calculates maximum timestep duration in the end, and when i write the big variable in one step, the max step is dramatically larger than before.

Comment: Yes, the maximum time step duration will be much larger, but the average time step duration should be less than if you wrote to the log at each step.